# Get index of child elements with event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Without changing the HTML, how can I get the index of each slide container when clicked on?

eg. they clicked on 2, how do I get a value such as `node[1]`?

```js
document.getElementById("slides").addEventListener("click", function(e){
 console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<section id="slides">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: One liner: Use event delegation and then do:
`const idx = Array.from(e.currentTarget.children).indexOf(e.target.closest(childClass));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you're not using arrow function syntax in your callback you can use `this` to reference the `slides` element. Using ES6 spread syntax, you can spread its child elements into an array and then use `indexOf` on that array to get the index of `e.target` within it:

```js
document.getElementById("slides").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const idx = [...this.children]
    .filter(el => el.className.indexOf('slide') > -1)
    .indexOf(e.target);

  if (idx > -1) {
    console.log(`Slide index: ${idx}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<section id="slides">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <span>Not a slide</span>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</section>
```

**Updated:**
I updated my answer to include only elements having the class `slide` by implementing the `filter` method - without this, the index could be thrown off by sibling elements that are not slides.

Comment: As a side note, if the sildes contain other elements and not just text, then replace `e.target` with `e.target.closest(".slide")` (check `closest` browser compatibility on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest))

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.indexOf()` and `.querySelectorAll()`, feeding it the list of divs and the target as arguments.

```js
document.getElementById("slides").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#slides > .slide');
  console.log([].indexOf.call(nodes, e.target));
});
```

```html
<section id="slides">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</section>
```